# Transposing data in Hive table

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, unpivot

I have read a few of the answers to questions similar to this one here but they are all somehow different. I have some data that sits in a hive table and what I would like to be able to do is to take 2 columns and move/append them to the bottom of my dataset. I would like to do this whilst retaining the information that was associated with that row previously and also combine 2 seperate date fields.

The data I have looks like this

```
ID     Action   Date/Time of Action  Date of Issue  Issue
1111    TypeA   01/02/2016           05/04/2016     IssueA
1111    TypeB   01/03/2016           05/04/2016     IssueA
1111    TypeB   03/03/2016           05/04/2016     IssueA
1111    TypeC   28/03/2016           05/04/2016     IssueA
2222    TypeB   01/02/2016           30/03/2016     IssueA
2222    TypeB   05/03/2016           30/03/2016     IssueA
2222    TypeC   28/03/2016           30/03/2016     IssueA
3333    TypeA   07/01/2016           27/01/2016     IssueB
3333    TypeB   03/01/2016           27/01/2016     IssueB
```

And what I would like to get to is this

```
ID      Action/Issue    Date-Time   Type
1111    TypeA           01/02/2016  Action
1111    TypeB           01/03/2016  Action
1111    TypeB           03/03/2016  Action
1111    TypeC           28/03/2016  Action
1111    IssueA          05/04/2016  Issue
2222    TypeB           01/02/2016  Action
2222    TypeB           05/03/2016  Action
2222    TypeC           28/03/2016  Action
2222    IssueA          30/03/2016  Issue
3333    TypeA           07/01/2016  Action
3333    TypeB           03/01/2016  Action
3333    IssueB          27/01/2016  Issue
```

I have seen some examples on here of how to use MAP and EXPLODE and have had a go at trying to use them but I am getting confused and they seem to relate more to pivoting data to make it wider whereas I want to go the other way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
select      ID
           ,Action      as Action_Issue
           ,Action_Date as DT
           ,'Action'    as TYP

from        mytable

union all

select      ID
           ,Issue       as Action_Issue   
           ,Issue_date  as DT
           ,'Issue'     as TYP

from        mytable

group by    ID
           ,Issue
           ,Issue_date
;
```

---

```
+--------+------------------+------------+---------+
| _u1.id | _u1.action_issue |   _u1.dt   | _u1.typ |
+--------+------------------+------------+---------+
|   1111 | TypeA            | 2016-02-01 | Action  |
|   1111 | TypeB            | 2016-03-01 | Action  |
|   1111 | TypeB            | 2016-03-03 | Action  |
|   1111 | TypeC            | 2016-03-28 | Action  |
|   2222 | TypeB            | 2016-02-01 | Action  |
|   2222 | TypeB            | 2016-03-05 | Action  |
|   2222 | TypeC            | 2016-03-28 | Action  |
|   3333 | TypeA            | 2016-01-07 | Action  |
|   3333 | TypeB            | 2016-01-03 | Action  |
|   1111 | IssueA           | 2016-04-05 | Issue   |
|   2222 | IssueA           | 2016-03-30 | Issue   |
|   3333 | IssueB           | 2016-01-27 | Issue   |
+--------+------------------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: If you care about the order of the results, wrap this query with additional select and then order.

Comment: Are you still here?